# another "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast" error i didnt understand

Tags: c, char, initialization, printf, string-literals

This code is supposed to print `valuesa` and adresses of variables using variable and pointer names and adresses. I get this `initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast` error.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>      
    
int main() {

    int m = 300;
    double fx = 300.6006;
    char z = "c";

    printf("%d\n %lf\n %c\n", m, fx, z);
    printf("%p\n %p\n %p\n", &m, &fx, &z);  

    int* ptr_m = &m;
    double* ptr_fx = &fx;
    char* ptr_z = &z;

    printf("%d\n %lf\n %c\n", *ptr_m, *ptr_fx, *ptr_z);
    printf("%p\n %p\n %p\n", &ptr_m, &ptr_fx, &ptr_z);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Can you help me fix this ?

Comment: Please always show the complete and exact error message. Normally it contains the line where it was detected. Then we don't need to guess which line might be causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
char z = "c";
```

with

```
char z = 'c';
```

Comment: it gave an error that says i should change ' character with "

Comment: ow it fixed thank youi should have made a mistake xd

Answer (score -1):

"c" is a character literal having the array type `char[2]`. It is represented in memory like array `{ 'c', '\0' }`. Used as an initializer expression it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *`. So in this declaration

```
char z = "c";
```

that is equivalent to the declaration

```
char z = &"c"[0];
```

you are trying to initialize the object `z` having the type `char` with a pointer of the type `char *`. Instead of the string literal you need to use an integer character constant like

```
char z = 'c';
```

In calls of `printf` like this

```
printf("%d\n %lf\n %c\n", m, fx, z);
```

the length modifier `l` in this format `%lf` is redundant and has no effect. You may write

```
printf("%d\n %f\n %c\n", m, fx, z);
```

Also you should cast pointers to the type `void *` in calls of `printf` like this

```
printf("%p\n %p\n %p\n", ( void * )&m, ( void * )&fx, ( void * )&z);
```

And it seems instead of this call of `printf`

```
printf("%p\n %p\n %p\n", &ptr_m, &ptr_fx, &ptr_z);
```

you mean this call

```
printf("%p\n %p\n %p\n", ( void * )ptr_m, ( void * )ptr_fx, ( void *)ptr_z);
```